# enum with integer for names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

in my User model Im trying to declare an enum with a name that contains a number, something like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
enum age_group: [
    '18_to_22',
    '23_to_27',
    '28_to_32',
    '33_to_37',
    '38_to_42'
  ]
end
```

but obviously that would produce a problem when the user object is called

error:

```
User.18_to_22 
syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting '('
User.18_to_22
```

is there a way around this other than use other names and dealing with the problem from the frontend side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum` creates scops in the model for the given values. And scope names can not start with integers. 
So the only workaround I can think of is something like:

```
enum age_group: [
  eighteen_to_twenty: '18_to_22',
  ...
  ...
]
```

OR

```
enum age_group: [
  _18_to_20: '18_to_22',
  ...
  ...
]
```

You can use it like `User.eighteen_to_twenty` or `User._18_to_22`

Comment: yeah I would agree both would work, but the first is too long to be used for example "thirty_eight_to_fourty_two" is just way too long. the second option is better but ugly :)

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use the convenience methods provided by `enum`, but you don't have to use those methods. You can use a more traditional `where` query:

```
User.where(age_group: '18_to_22')
```

If you prefer to use the convenience methods, they are still available to you using `send`, but I don't think it's as clear as using `where`:

```
User.send('18_to_22')
```

Comment: using send here is not really clear, I think Im going to stick to just using the old fashioned where, thank you